# Cross product of two vectors is same despite transposing one of them

Tags: cross-product

Just wondering why the cross product is the same in both case:

```
const first = [1,2,1];
const second = [2,4,2];

console.log(math.cross(first,math.transpose(second)));
// [ 0, 0, 0 ]


console.log(math.cross(first,second));
// [ 0, 0, 0 ]
```

should they be the same? How does that work if one is transposed?

(Ultimately I am just trying to discover if the vectors are linearly independent or not.)

Comment: I don't believe the transpose carries any meaning in this context.  They should compute to the same vector in any case.  The example you give is not relevant because the vectors are parallel.  My suggestion...  Do the same calculation with the vectors $[1,2,1]$ and $[3,4,5]$ on the computer, as you have written.  I predict they will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{x}\times 2 \mathbf{x}=0$

why?

using indicial tensor notation and

Einstein's summation convention (repeated index is a sum)

we have:

$(\mathbf{x}\times \mathbf{2x})_i=2\epsilon_{ijk}x_jx_k$

Where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the alternating tensor.

So exchanging indices $j,k$ and using the antisymmetry of $\epsilon_{ijk}$ we obtain the zero result.

ln a more intuitive way,  think of a cross product as rotating one vector counterclockwise to another vector.

If the angle between the vectors is 0, then there is no rotation.

Hence, the product is 0.